# What's "auto" value in "AC_ARG_ENABLE"?

Tags: configure, autotools, autoconf

I've been checking whether which files of some open source components are used during compile.
But, I don't know well about autotools, autoconf, etc.. so, I want to know the "auto" value means in AC_ARG_ENABLE(). Here is an example.

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(launchd, AS_HELP_STRING(--description--),enable_launchd=$enableval,enable_launchd=auto)
```

If "--enable-launchd" option is given, run the command "enable_launchd=$enableval", right??
But if not, run the command "enable_lauchd=auto".
What is a value of the "auto"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If "--enable-launchd" option is given, run the command
>   "enable_launchd=$enableval", right??

Right.

> But if not, run the command
>   "enable_lauchd=auto".

Yes.

> What is a value of the "auto"?

"auto" has no significance in that command other than as itself.  It *is* the value assigned to variable `enable_launchd`.

You may well find that `configure.ac` later checks for that value and performs additional processing if it is seen, or you might find that it just emits it as-is into an external file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
But I'm still curious about the value..because after that statement the following statement is seen,

`if test x$enable_launchd = xno ; then`
`....`
`else`
`....`
`fi`

If the option is not given, the value is set to the auto. Then what condition statement is executed in the if else statement above?

Comment: I don't think you're getting it yet, @euns.  The value assigned to `enable_launchd` is literally `"auto"`.  In that case, `x$enable_launchd` expands to `xauto`, which is unequal to `xno`, so the `else` branch of that `if` statement is executed.

Comment: Ah..I originally thought the variable `enable_launchd` could be assigned to two values only, `yes` or `no`. But now I understood it could be assigned to `auto`, too. Thanks @John